# Photoshop: Text on top of image looks bad when saved for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I put text over an image and then save as a jpeg using the File -> Save for Web defaults I always end up seeing noise in the text even though it's 100% opacity..

This a a screen shot of what I see in Photoshop:

[image: photoshop]

And this is a screen shot of the jpeg after saving. I think the noise I'm describing is most visible in the "A" and the left diagonal of the "Y".

[image: savdd-jpeg]

It's not on an edge/corner so I don't think it's an anti-aliasing issue. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is JPEG compression. You're setting the quality of your *.jpg at a low value, causing the compression algorithm to create this 'noise' -- JPEG is notoriusly bad at areas of identical or similar colour.

In the 'Save for Web' dialog box, try and set the quality to something around 60~70 and try again. If that isn't enough, try an even higher value.

In case 100 quality doesn't satisfy, you'd better try another file type altogether, like PNG-24 or even GIF.